# Docker private registry: got 400 bad request when docker push

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, docker-registry

I'm trying to build a private docker registry on my server.

I made a docker-compose project using `registry` image.

Nginx is used for reverse proxy from `hub.topfyf.cn` to `localhost:5000`.

I tried `docker pull ubuntu && docker tag ubuntu hub.topfyf.cn/test && docker push hub.topfyf.cn/test`, which succeeded.

Then I tried to build a `buildx` multi-platform image and used `--push` tag, which failed.

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push hub.topfyf.cn/debtnet-api:latest: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:031b4812772bb44ba2f196d0f9fa66c8e2f27e061aaee7c9cfe00c8fcd204210": unexpected status from PUT request to https://hub.topfyf.cn/v2/debtnet-api/manifests/sha256:031b4812772bb44ba2f196d0f9fa66c8e2f27e061aaee7c9cfe00c8fcd204210: 400 Bad Request
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
# Docker compose for docker registry
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    container_name: registry
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd
      - REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm
      - REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd
    volumes:
      - ./auth:/auth
      - registry-data:/var/lib/registry
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
volumes:
  registry-data:
    driver: local
```

This is my nginx configuration:

```
user www www;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /www/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  crit;
pid /www/server/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

stream {
    log_format tcp_format '$time_local|$remote_addr|$protocol|$status|$bytes_sent|$bytes_received|$session_time|$upstream_addr|$upstream_bytes_sent|$upstream_bytes_received|$upstream_connect_time';

    access_log /www/wwwlogs/tcp-access.log tcp_format;
    error_log /www/wwwlogs/tcp-error.log;
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/tcp/*.conf;
}

events
{
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 51200;
    multi_accept on;
}

http
{
    include       mime.types;
    #include luawaf.conf;

    include proxy.conf;
    lua_package_path "/www/server/nginx/lib/lua/?.lua;;";

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
    client_header_buffer_size 32k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    sendfile   on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    keepalive_timeout 60;

    tcp_nodelay on;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1k;
    gzip_buffers     4 16k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
    limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m;

    server_tokens off;
    access_log off;

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name hub.topfyf.cn;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
        root /www/wwwroot/hub.topfyf.cn;
    
        # for Let's Encrypt verification
        include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/well-known/hub.topfyf.cn.conf;
    
        if ($server_port !~ 443){
            rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
        }
        ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/hub.topfyf.cn/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/hub.topfyf.cn/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:TLSSSL:16m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
        error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    
        location ~ /purge(/.*) {
            proxy_cache_purge cache_one $host$1$is_args$args;
            #access_log  /www/wwwlogs/hub.topfyf.cn_purge_cache.log;
        }
    
        location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.env|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
        {
            return 404;
        }
    
        location ~ \.well-known{
            allow all;
        }
    
        if ( $uri ~ "^/\.well-known/.*\.(php|jsp|py|js|css|lua|ts|go|zip|tar\.gz|rar|7z|sql|bak)$" ) {
            return 403;
        }
    
        access_log  /www/wwwlogs/hub.topfyf.cn.log;
        error_log  /www/wwwlogs/hub.topfyf.cn.error.log;
    
        location /
        {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
    }
}
```